# Structure to hold uneven dynamic matrix?

Tags: c, data-structures, matrix, struct

I would like to create a matrix structure that has uneven rows like the one below:

```
[0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] 
[0] [0] [0] [0]
```

Therefore I would like to store somewhere its column length as well as the widths of each row. My implementation is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    int *data;
} dyn_row;

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    dyn_row *row;
} dyn_matrix;

int main(void) {

    int i, j;
    dyn_matrix matrix;

    srand(time(NULL));
    // Allocate
    matrix.size = 5;
    matrix.row = malloc(matrix.size * sizeof(dyn_row));
    for (i=0; i<matrix.size; i++) {
        matrix.row[i].size = rand()%(i+1)+2;
        matrix.row[i].data = malloc((matrix.row[i].size) * sizeof(int));
    }
    // Initialize
    for (i=0; i<matrix.size; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<matrix.row[i].size; j++) {
            matrix.row[i].data[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    // Print values & free
    for (i=0; i<matrix.size; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<matrix.row[i].size; j++) {
            printf("[%d] ", matrix.row[i].data[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(matrix.row[i].data);
    }
    free(matrix.row);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it a good solution? What is the optimal implementation to solve this problem? Also, is it a good practice instead of "int *data" to write "void *data" so the matrix can hold any type of data?

Comment: What you have is a reasonable solution. If you're only concerned with arrays of `int`, using `int *` is better than `void *`.  If you know you're going to be storing other types, then a `void *` solution allows some things to work, but dereferencing the data will be a fiddly process involving casts.  You're better off with the accurate concrete type rather than trying `void *`, in general.  Also, random access to a cell (i,j) requires checking.

Comment: Asking whether a working solution is a good one should probably be posted on [codereview.se] [instead of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) here (if you haven't tested it yet, you should do so before posting it here). "Optimal" is which regard? Space? Time? Readability of the code? `void` pointers has this habit of turning compile-time errors into runtime errors, which is a bad thing, and affects readability of the code (so should probably be avoided if possible).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew that what you were trying to achieve is known as a "jagged array" you might find many more examples; though you will also find that other languages support this data structure better.

Allocating the data is the trivial part, but you would would do well to define separate functions for allocating and accessing the array to wrap these operations safely (access bounds checking, memory management etc.) .  For example you might define:

```
typedef dyn_matrix* tJaggedArray ;

// Create n rows of initially zero length
tJaggedArray jaggedCreate( int rows ) ; 

// Set the length and allocate a row in array
tJaggedArray jaggedAllocRow( tJaggedArray array, int row, int length ) ;

// Get an array element, return true if element exists, else false
bool jaggedGet( tJaggedArray array, int row, int col, int* value ) ;

// Set an array element, return true if element exists, else false
bool jaggedSet( tJaggedArray array, int row, int col, int value ) ;

// Clean up array resources
void jaggedDestroy( tJaggedArray array ) ;
```

In C++ you could of course wrap this in a class so you would not have to pass the array pointer to every function, and you could use a template to support arrays of different types, and operator overloading to make the array access look like built-in array accesses.  In C# the bounds checking is built-in to the language.